# How to ask for more quota persistent space via javascript on chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using below code to request more `Quota` space in chrome:

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
    requestedBytes, function(grantedBytes) {
        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);

    }, function(e) { console.log('Error', e); }
);
```

but got this error:

```
VM4144:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: onInitFs is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:60
```

Does anyone know how I can request more quota?

Comment: The error message means that onInitFs and errorHandler should be functions defined in your code.

Comment: ok I am so stupid. Thanks for your help

Comment: In such cases always blame MDN :-) Some of their sample code is overcomplicated and confusing.